# Compare two files in efi shell (.nsh) and paste result to if statement

Tags: shell, intel, bios, uefi

How can I check if the `comp` function (https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/efi-shells-and-scripting)  from efi shell returns true?

```
if comp file1 file2
```

doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you're playing with the UEFI shell you don't need an if statement.

```
comp file1 file2
```

If the two files are equal in size and content, the shell will return a message saying "[no differences encountered]". Otherwise, it will return a message saying what was the difference. For instance a "File size mismatch" or a "Content difference" saying which lines differ.